# How to test a component that fetches data in useEffect and stores it in state with react-testing-library and jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm fairly new to react-testing-library and generally testing. I want to test a component that fetches the data from an API in useEffect hook. Then it stores it in local state. It renders these array data with array.map, but i'm getting `Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')]` error. I'm probably doing wrong in my test suite, i've researched a lot but couldn't fix it.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
    import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
    import { rest } from 'msw';
    import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';

    import { OnePiece } from '.';

    const server = setupServer(rest.get('server http address', (req, res, ctx) => {
        const totalData = [
            { name: "doffy", price: 100, image: "image url" },
            { name: "lamingo", price: 500, image: "image url" }
        ];
        return res(
            ctx.status(200),
            ctx.json({
                data: { crew: totalData }
            })
        )
    }))
    beforeAll(() => server.listen());
    afterAll(() => server.close());
    beforeEach(() => server.restoreHandlers());

    //console.log("mocking axios", axios)
    describe('OnePiece', () => {
        
        test('fetches the data from the API and correctly renders it', async () => {
            //Here's probably where i fail. Please someone tell me the right way :) 
            await render(<OnePiece />)
            const items = await screen.findAllByAltText('product-image');
            expect(items).toHaveLength(2);
            //     screen.debug()
        })
    })
```

And the below is the parts of code useEffect, and totalData.map in the component:

```
const [totalData, setTotalData] = useState([]);
const [crew, setCrew] = useState('straw-hat-pirates');

 useEffect(() => {
    let isApiSubscribed = true;
    const getOpData = async () => {
        const getCrews = await axios.get('http address');
        if (isApiSubscribed) {
            let data = getCrews.data;
            data = data[crew];
            // console.log("data", data);
            setTotalData(data);
        }
    }
    getOpData();
    return () => {
        isApiSubscribed=false;
    }
}, [crew])
.........

//in the return part
 <ProductsWrapper>
            {totalData.map((product, index) =>
                <ProductCard key={index} name={product.name} price={product.price} imageUrl={product.image} />
            )}
        </ProductsWrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i predicted, the problem was the async data fetching. Currently setTimeOut is more than enough for me, but if someone sees this in the future, you can look for the **waitFor** method of react-testing-library.
Here's the fixed part:

```
  describe('OnePiece', () => {
      test('fetches the data from the API and correctly renders it', async () => {
          render(<OnePiece />)
          setTimeout(async () => {
              const items = await screen.findAllByAltText('product-image');
              expect(items).toHaveLength(2);
            }, 4000)
            //screen.debug()
        })
    })
```

Comment: If you use setTimeout it will not work properly, you can define something which doesn't work but your test will anyway pass.